# Why do the locations of the solutions to $e^z = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}2 + \frac{\sqrt{2}}2 i\;$ "make sense"?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Find all values of $z$ such that
> $$e^z = \frac{-\sqrt{2}}2 + \frac{\sqrt{2}}2 i$$
> Where are these roots located? Why does their location make sense?

I found that $z = \pi (\frac{3}4 + 2n)i$ and it is clear that these roots are on the Imaginary axis. But why does their location "make sense"? I don't understand the purpose of the question.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe the answer is a simple as "$e^z$ has a period of $2\pi i$ because both cosine and sine have a period of $2\pi$".

Answer (score 1):

If any non-zero complex number can be written as $e^z=e^{x+iy}=e^xe^{iy}$ for some $x$ and $y$ real, then $|e^xe^{iy}|=e^x$.

$\Big|\frac{-\sqrt{2}}2 + \frac{\sqrt{2}}2 i\Big|=1$ so here you need $e^x=1$ and $x=0$ and *it makes sense* all the possible $z$ are purely imaginary

Comment: Uhm, i understand what you said but still, u have not answered why the locations i.e. on the imaginary axis make sense.

Comment: Points on the unit circle, and only those points, get sent to sets of points on the imaginary axis.  All other points get sent to points with a real component, which depends on the original points' magnitude.  So it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

A good intuition for understanding complex roots of exponentials of $e$ is that they are analogous to standard trigonometry of the unit circle.

$e^{i\pi} = -1$ turns out to be $e^{i\pi} = \cos(\pi)+i\sin(\pi) = -1$. Therefore, the roots are essentially angles upon the given circle given by $e^{z}$, which fall on
$$\frac{-\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i.$$

Comment: I understand partly but it is still confusing.